# Reduce tick marks in xyplot in R

Tags: r, lattice

I have tried looking for the answer to this but none of the solutions have worked. I have created a plot with the following code:

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(Births.Registered..Number. ~ X, data=CSOStats, scales=list(
y=list(tick.number = 10)))
```

I have been able to change the tick marks for the y axis. I want to decrease the amount of tick marks for the x axis as well. The dates on the x axis are in this format "1960Q1", "1960Q2", etc. I have not been able to reduce the amount of ticks on the graph while maintaining the names of the respective tick. Ideally, I would be able to see a tick every 5 years (which is every 20 ticks), but I can't achieve this. Here is a picture of the graph at present.

[image]

Comment: You should provide some data. Have you tried just defining x scales? `scales=list(y=list(tick.number = 10), x=list(at=where.you.want.them, labels=your.labels))`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know how to use the 'at' argument. Used a sequence and now it works perfectly.

xyplot(Marriages.Registered..Number. ~ X, data=CSOStats, scales=list(x=list(tick.number = 20, at = seq(1, 212, 20)), y=list(tick.number = 10)))

Answer (score 1):

`tick.number` does not work for `character` or `factor` (from `?xyplot`):

> ‘tick.number’ An integer, giving the suggested number of
>                 intervals between ticks.  This is ignored for a factor,
>                 shingle, or character vector, for in these cases there is
>                 no natural rule for leaving out some of the labels.

But you could use `at` and `labels`, e.g.:

```
library("lattice")

## example data
df <- data.frame(x=paste0(rep(1960:1999, each=4), paste0("Q", 1:4)), y=1:160)

## calculate position and create labels
x.tick.number <- 10
at <- seq(1, nrow(df), length.out=x.tick.number)
labels <- round(seq(1960, 1999, length.out=x.tick.number))

xyplot(y ~ x, data=df, scales=list(y=list(tick.number=10), 
                                   x=list(at=at, labels=labels, rot=90)))
```

[image]